# Bash: Create a file if it does not exist, otherwise check to see if it is writeable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash program that will write to an output file.  This file may or may not exist, but the script must check permissions and fail early.  I can't find an elegant way to make this happen.  Here's what I have tried.

```
set +e
touch $file
set -e

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit;fi
```

I keep `set -e` on for this script so it fails if there is ever an error on any line.  Is there an easier way to do the above script?

Comment: I must warn you that there is a race condition. You cannot check for an error early. File could have been there by the time you checked, but got removed by the time you are about to start writing into it. Or even worse, permission changed. I recommend you open file for writing and get descriptor. If that operation succeeded, you good. In that case it doesn't matter if file got removed or not, OS will keep inode open in case of removal and just "de-touch" it from file name.

Comment: Help me understand.  If the log file is deleted while the script is running, then attempts to write to it will succeed if I open a descriptor?  But the file is deleted..where does the data go?  Wouldn't I want it to fail in those rare cases?

Comment: If a file is deleted (more specifically, unlinked) whilst open for writing it remains in the filesystem until all filehandles are closed, either explicitly or by the process(es) exiting. If your process is the only thing writing to the file, it will continue to fill up the disk, but won't be able to be opened (because there is no directory entry) by any other process.

Comment: @Phil.  Thanks for the explanation.  This sounds like a bad thing for this script.  Filling up the disk with unreachable data isn't going to help me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Rather than check `$?` on a different line, check the return value immediately like this:

```
touch file || exit
```

As long as your `umask` doesn't restrict the write bit from being set, you can just rely on the return value of `touch`

Comment: Note that you don't have to `set +e` with this, since `-e` only affects simple commands.  Also, if you want to print an error message, you can use `touch file || { echo "Cannot write to file" >&2; exit 1 }`

Comment: @Gordon Good call on the `-e`. Also, I originally had the error message but then I realized that `touch` does a mighty fine job already: `touch: cannot touch '/root/blah': Permission denied`

Comment: This is not robust: it ensures the file could be written *when you run `touch`*. It may not be writable later when you need it. Depending on the scenario, this could cause race conditions or security holes.

Comment: Note that this will change the last modification time of the file, even if you don't write to it.

Comment: Note the correct syntax is `touch "$file" 2>/dev/null || { echo "Cannot write to $file" >&2; exit 1; }`. Grouping commands using same shell: `{ list; }` require an ending semicolon (or newline) after the list. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping
I add also error redirect of touch command to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 42):

Why complicate things?

```
file=exists_and_writeable

if ! [ -e "$file" ] ; then
    touch "$file"
fi

if ! [ -w "$file" ] ; then
    printf 'cannot write to %s\n' "$file"
    exit 1
fi
```

Or, more concisely,

```
{ [ -e "$file" ] || touch "$file"; } && \
    ! [ -w "$file" ] && printf 'cannot write to %s' "$file" && exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `-w` to check if a file is writable (search for it in the bash man page).

```
if [[ ! -w $file ]]; then exit; fi
```

Comment: That would have to be done after the touch command since the file might not exist beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Why must the script fail early? By separating the writable test and the file open() you introduce a race condition. Instead, why not try to open (truncate/append) the file for writing, and deal with the error if it occurs? Something like:

```
$ echo foo > output.txt
$ if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then die("Couldn't echo foo")
```

As others mention, the "noclobber" option might be useful if you want to avoid overwriting existing files.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file for writing. In the shell, this is done with an output redirection. You can redirect the shell's standard output by putting the redirection on the `exec` built-in with no argument.

```
set -e
exec >shell.out  # exit if shell.out can't be opened
echo "This will appear in shell.out"
```

Make sure you haven't set the `noclobber` option (which is useful interactively but often unusable in scripts). Use `>` if you want to truncate the file if it exists, and `>>` if you want to append instead.

If you only want to test permissions, you can run `: >foo.out` to create the file (or truncate it if it exists).

If you only want some commands to write to the file, open it on some other descriptor, then redirect as needed.

```
set -e
exec 3>foo.out
echo "This will appear on the standard output"
echo >&3 "This will appear in foo.out"
echo "This will appear both on standard output and in foo.out" | tee /dev/fd/3
```

(`/dev/fd` is not supported everywhere; it's available at least on Linux, *BSD, Solaris and Cygwin.)